# Is there a way to paste a statement with column-names and use it to create a new column in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, paste

I have a df,

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c('1','0', '1','1', '1'), X2 = c('1','0', '1','0', '1'), X3 = c('1','0', '1','0', '1'), X4 = c('1','0', '1','0', '1'))
```

And I would like to create a number of testcases along the columns that says

'1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1'

And so on for each row. My expected output is

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c('1','0', '1','1', '1'), X2 = c('1','0', '1','0', '1'), X3 = c('1','0', '1','0', '1'), X4 = c('1','0', '1','0', '1'), tc= c("1 & 1 & 1 & 1", "0 & 0 & 0 & 0", "1 & 1 & 1 & 1", "1 & 0 & 0 & 0", "1 & 1 & 1 & 1"))
```

I am not sure if this is the most simple way to do it. But I build a string with noquote, toString and lapply:

```
string <-  noquote(toString(lapply(1:3, function(x){noquote(sprintf("df$X%s, '&'", x))})))
string
#df$X1, '&', df$X2, '&', df$X3, '&'
```

And try to activate it with paste

```
df$tc <- paste(string, df$X4)
```

However it only paste the last value from X4 making my testcases look like:

```
head(df$tc)

[1] "df$X1, '&', df$X2, '&', df$X3, '&' 1" "df$X1, '&', df$X2, '&', df$X3, '&' 0"
[3] "df$X1, '&', df$X2, '&', df$X3, '&' 1" "df$X1, '&', df$X2, '&', df$X3, '&' 0"
[5] "df$X1, '&', df$X2, '&', df$X3, '&' 1"
```

The only solution I have found is to copy the string I created into a paste statement

```
df$tc <-paste(df$X1, '&', df$X2, '&', df$X3, '&', df$X4)
```

However, it does not look good, and sometimes I have more than 100 testcases and a very long string.

Is there anyway that I can paste the results in like this;

```
df$tc <- paste(string, df$X4)
```

Or is there a more clever approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `do.call` with `paste`

```
df$tc <- do.call(paste, c(df, sep=" & "))
df$tc
#[1] "1 & 1 & 1 & 1" "0 & 0 & 0 & 0" "1 & 1 & 1 & 1" "1 & 0 & 0 & 0" "1 & 1 & 1 & 1"
```

---

Or with `reduce` and `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(tc = reduce(., str_c, sep=" & "))
```

Answer (score 2):

additional solution

```
library(stringr)
df$tc <- apply(df, 1, function(x) str_c(x, collapse = " & "))
```